# Record audio then save it in webgl

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am working on a webgl project in Unity3d where i need to record audio and then prompt the user to save the audio file in his device.
I searched a lot in stack and in the internet but i couldn't find any solution? any help please ?

Comment: This question is way to broad! Did you try anything so far? e.g. https://forum.unity.com/threads/record-microphone-to-file.415078/

Comment: @derHugo that question if not for webgl. "Microphone" is not supported in webgl.
I am hoping that someone have a tested unity asset or an article that can help me.

Comment: look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/webgl-audio.html) what is and what is not supported in webGL. `Anything not listed here is not currently supported on WebGL.` You might want to go through [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-and-microphone.308197/) I found but it seems very tricky to do what you want (some of the links are also down there)